# Transfer letters from buttons to jLabel component

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel

How can I transfer the value of a button and display it as a string in a `JLabel`? For example, when a button with a value of "A" is pressed, I want the text of the `JLabel` component set to "A".

Comment: Well, in simplest terms it would be `label.setText(...)`, but I think you have more complex problem at hand.  Maybe do some research into "model-view-controller" and "observer pattern"

Comment: Maybe you should start with [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Labels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

Comment: did you mean [`JButton button = new JButton("A");
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setText(button.getText());`](https://ideone.com/zwGi92)

Answer (score 1):

Add listener to JButton and if it's clicked then `setText("A")` on your JLabel

Answer (score 1):

Use the listener on button click and set Text to jLabel.

```
jButton.setOnClickListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
     JButton button = (JButton)actionEvent.getSource();
     jLabel.setText(button.getText());
  }
});
```